# How to describe change in dependent data?

Tags: correlation, independence

I have observations that were measured before and after an operation, say $X_{before}$  and $X_{after}$. I am interested in the amount of change (either increase or decrease). How could I describe it? I am wondering whether it is possible to say something like this: "There is an increase of 60%"

My data are as follows:

```
X_{before}  X_{after}
 3.2         3.4
 2.8         2.7
  .           .
  .           .
7.5          7.8
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I would do.

First, calculate the mean difference.  In order to do this, define $D_i=X_{after,i}-X_{before,i}$, where $i=1,\ldots,n$, then the the average of all $D_i$.  This is a good way to estimate the difference between the $before$ and $after$ groups.

Second, evaluate whether or not the difference $D$ is statistically different from $0$ by executing a $t$-test.  If the $p$-value from the $t$-test is sufficiently small, then we can conclude that there is a statistically significant difference between the $before$ and $after$ groups.